# Dialogflow CX - transitioning to previous page from a route group does not re-prompt

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I have a "go back" route group that allows the user to go back to the previous page. While this is working, i.e. the flow indeed moves back to the previous page, the agent is not prompting the user after it navigates back.

In other words, let's say we have page A with prompt "Welcome to page A", then page B with prompt "Welcome to page B". User is on B, and tells the agent to go back; I expected to see the "Welcome to page A" prompt again, but the agent doesn't say anything.

Of course, adding the prompt to the "go back" route defeats the purpose, since we want to reuse it across the flow. How can I force the prompt to happen in this particular case?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [PREVIOUS_PAGE](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/handler#symbolic), the page state from the previous page (Page B to A) will be restored after the transition. In this case, entry fulfilment or prompts will not be shown once the previous page is restored.

I believe only those unfilled parameters/fields/variables will be shown. In this sense, such use-case is an expected behaviour (no prompts will be shown when transitioning to previous page).

Comment: While I understand this is the expected behavior, I was trying to find out if there is a straightforward way to make the Agent prompt the user again. From a user experience perspective, it's weird to say "Back" and receive nothing in response.

Comment: You could create an intent with training phrases like "back to page A"  and from page B create a route that go back to page A with the intent created earlier. But you must have told the user from the first prompt how to go about it